# JS delegate unique event (one()) for dynamic declared elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on js-project. Some parts of HTML is generating via JS like this:

```
html += '<div class="button"><a href="' + url1 + '>' + button_text1 + '</a></div>';
html += '<div class="button"><a href="' + url2 + '>' + button_text2 + '</a></div>';
```

What I want is create listener to the first click for each of the buttons.

**Idea 1:** Use `$(.button a).live('click', doSomething)` because of dynamic declaration. Sadly, there's no way to force trigger only on the first click like that. Also deprecated.

**Idea 2:** Use `$(.button a).one('click', doSomething)`. Not working because of `on()` might fail to find selector when DOM is ready, but still rendering (`$(document).ready(...)`). See details here: https://jqueryhouse.com/jquery-on-method-the-issue-of-dynamically-added-elements/

**Idea 3:** Use `$(body).one('click', '.button a', doSomething)`, i.e. delegate event as noted source suggests. 
But it seems like JS is read it not as "Here is an array of elements; for each element add `one('click')` event", but as "Add `one('click')` event for click on any element from an array", because an event is triggered only once no matter what button I have clicked.

I was really trying to find any clues to how manage this situation but got no luck. I will be really grateful for help or another idea how to solve this!

Comment: Can't you just add a class that will act as a flag? After you click on the element, add that class (Say `btn-clicked`) and then in the event you can check `if( $(this).hasClass('btn-clicked') ) { return; }` (Of course, don't forget to actually add that class after the if statement)  - Then you don't need to use `one()` and you can use `on()` with delegation

Comment: `live` has not been in jQuery versions since 2013....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *«I want is create listener to the first click for each of the buttons.»*

The keyword here is **each**.

Try that:

```
$(.button a).each(function(){
  $(this).one('click', doSomething); // (!)No prenthesis here... Just the function name.
});
```

Documentation for the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method.

Since you append new elements dynamically... After you appended `html` to a container, run a similar each loop on them like this:

```
// Assuming you do this
$(".container_selector").append(html);

// Then run the each loop
$(".container_selector").find(".button a").each(function(){
  $(this).one('click', doSomething); // (!)No prenthesis here... Just the function name.
});
```

Comment: Thanks to @AlonEitan for letting me know that OP wants my answer back ;) Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are overthinking things. So use event delegation and some flag that says if it has run or not.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.test', function() {
  var elem = $(this)  // what was clicked
  if (elem.data('clicked')) {  // see if we clicked it
    return false  // if yes, ignore the click
  }
  elem.data('clicked', true)  // mark it was clicked
  elem.html((new Date).toLocaleString())  // do something
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
```

Or go off a class that has not run and remove it

```js
$(document).on('click', '.test-run', function() {
  var elem = $(this)  // what was clicked
  elem.removeClass('test-run')  // remove class so will not be clickable
  elem.html((new Date).toLocaleString())  // do something
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test test-run">1</div>
<div class="test test-run">2</div>
<div class="test test-run">3</div>
<div class="test test-run">4</div>
```