# replace text with select menu

Tags: jquery, ajax, function, select

I created a script that replaces text in a html page with text from an external .txt document, with the help of jquery. But somehow it doesn't work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
 $('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function(){
 if ($(this).val() == "2"){
    $.ajax({url: "demo_test2.txt", success: function(result){
        $("#div2").html(result);
    }});
 });
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

<div id="div2"><h2>John</h2></div>

<select name="dropdown">
<option id="button" value="1">English</option>
<option id="button2" value="2">Dutch</option>
</select>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You placed the script tag containing your code before the HTML markup... So the elements targetted by the selectors `select[name="dropdown"]` and `#div2` does not yet exist when the code is parsed.

So you can place the script tag containing your code at the end of the file, just above `</body>` **or** wrap your code with a [*document ready*](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  // Add this
  $('select[name="dropdown"]').change(function(){
  if ($(this).val() == "2"){
    $.ajax({
      url: "demo_test2.txt",
      success: function(result){
        $("#div2").html(result);
      },
      error: function(request,status,error){
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
});  // And this
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="div2"><h2>John</h2></div>

  <select name="dropdown">
    <option id="button" value="1">English</option>
    <option id="button2" value="2">Dutch</option>
  </select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: pssst.... the OP [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52971068/754119) that you undelete your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52970447/754119) so he can accept it :)

Comment: I added an error callback to you ajax request... Look at the console for an error message. That is the only possible bug I can think of.